# Getting data of a row to a modal with two parameters with codeigniter 3

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter-3

My team and I are making a project wherein we need to pass on variables to a modal. How do I pass the data to the modal using `loan id` as parameter from the table row that I selected?

example:

| loan id | name | view |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0964 | charles | button |
| 0562 | ultor | button |

when you press the button of that particular row, a modal will show up wherein the details of that row will be loaded.

In addition, the modal will also have information that would be needed, but is from a different database table, but the parameter is `name` instead of `loan id`

Is there a way to do that? I don't have a lot of experience in jquery and ajax, but i read that it might be a solution to my problem.

here is my table view that shows the button and the row information.

```
<?php foreach($open_applications as $row): ?>
<tr>
    <td><?php echo $row->col_full_name; ?></strong><td>
    <td><?php echo $row->col_loan_assignid; ?></td>
    <td>
        <button class="btn btn-secondary btn-xs" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#loanDecision">Pending</button>
        <a href="<?php echo site_url('Users/borrowerdetails')?>" role="button" class="btn btn-link btn-xs">View</button>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Here is my modal where it would need to show information that are in the row and information from a different table

```
<div class="modal fade" id="loanDecision" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="loanDecisionLabel" aria-hidden="true">
<div class="modal-dialog modal-lg modal-dialog-centered">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header border-0">
            <h5 class="modal-title" id="loanDecisionLabel">This would be where the name is from the row</h5><br>
        </div>

        <div class="modal-header">
            <h5 class="modal-title" id="loanDecisionSubtitle">this would be where the person's job is from the row</h5>
        </div>
        
        <div class="modal-body">
            <div class="table-responsive">
                <table class="table table-hover table-bordered">
                    <thead class="thead">
                        <tr>
                            <th scope="col">title of the column from a different table</th>
                            <th scope="col">title of the column from a different table</th>
                            <th scope="col">title of the column from a different table</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
    
                            <td>data from the column from the different table</td>
                            <td>data from the column from the different table</td>
                            <td>data from the column from the different table</td>
                            <td>data from the column from the different table</td>
                            <td>data from the column from the different table</td>
                            <td>data from the column from the different table</td>
                            <td>data from the column from the different table</td>
                        </tr>
                        
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I have created a controller and a model, but I don't know how to connect them to the modal, but here is my controller and model:

```
public function fetchDetails($col_loan_assignid, $col_borrower_id)
    {
        $data['getloandetails'] = $this->Users_model->getingloandetails($col_loan_assignid);
        $data['getactiondetails'] = $this->Users_model->getingactiondetails($col_borrower_id);
    }


    public function getingloandetails($col_loan_assignid){
        $sql = "select * from $this->tbl_loan_application where col_loan_assignid like '%$col_loan_assignid%'";
        $query = $this->db->query($sql);
        return $query->result();
    }

    public function getactiondetails($col_borrower_id){
        $sql = "select * from $this->tbl_action where col_loan_assignid like '%$col_borrower_id%'";
        $query = $this->db->query($sql);
        return $query->result();
    }
```

Comment: a modal window is just html, styled with css and behavior controlled by javascript (AJAX), so write your code as it would be a "normal" html output: the model gets the mySQL data and the controller processes this data and outputs an array when loading a view (your modal window). Read up on AJAX: controller is called from AJAX (your current view), model delivers data; controller echos the modal view and data, AJAX success displays it in browser

Answer (score 0):

Step 1 : set unique id to data attributes in view button.

Example `data-loanid='".$row->loanid."'`

Step 2 : add a common class to view button and add event-listner to it.

Example `view-btn`

Step 3 : after adding event listener get data attributes from its. So you can able to access unique.

```
$(".view-btn").click(function(){
        let loan_id=$(this).data('loanid');
        console.log(loan_id);
    });
```

Step 4 : after getting unique id so can able send a request via ajax or fetch api.

Step 5: on ci3 create a route and validate data in controller and pass data to model and fetch data from database and return response.

Fetch api Example

```js
let ApiRequest = async function(Url,param) {
        try {
            const url = Url;
            const options = {
                method: 'POST',
                mode: 'cors',
                cache: 'no-cache',
                credentials: 'same-origin',
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
                },
                body: param,
                //body:field1=Value1&field2=value2
            }
            const response = await fetch(url, options);
            // response as json
           return await response.json();
        } catch (error) {
            console.error('Error:', error);
            return false;
        }
}

let url="http://www.example.com/api/getdata";
let parameter=field1=Value1&field2=value2;
let Result=ApiRequest(url,parameter);
console.log(Result);
```

Comment: Hey, so I'm deffo new to ajax so I would appreciate it if you would cite me an example to "send a request via ajax" in my case?

Comment: you can use fetchapi to send request. bcs I am much likely to it